# Rails protect_from_forgery problems and warning with C#/unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, protect-from-forgery

I just get my hands on rails' protect_from_forgery, and I have written a simple login for my app as below:

Client-side

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<%= form_for :session do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :pw %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :pw %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

At the server side, in my application_controller.rb I have

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

I have tried login from the page, and it seems OK; at least I can login. However, I'd have a few questions to ask (I am on win OS)

1. I couldn't find any detail on the options for protect_from_forgery; I'd appreciate if anyone of any side that I can get a detailed explanation on that the options following  with: null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
2. How can I tell if my form is using and passing the CSRF authentication? I can see from the console in the set of params the form sent there is an 'authenticity_token', is this the one? If yes, how is it generated/defined? As I see that it is the same every time.

Also, I have another application (written in Unity3D c#) doing below, connect to the same server:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm(); 
form.AddField("id", id); 
form.AddField("pw", pw);   
WWW www = new WWW(mainUrl + "login/", form);
```

This time, again my client can still login, but on from the console I can see there is a warning as below

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

I have googled on this, but it seems most answer is to say I should just add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`, but this will just simply bypass the security check no? But I need the security check here so then it makes no sense to me...

How could I fix this and ensure that my login session is checked with protect_from_forgery?

Thanks all in advance for helping me on my questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have so many questions and I will not explain each one, but to give you some prompt.
First, you can find the detail explanation of `protect_from_forgery` from [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

And also [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) will give more info about CSRF.

```
<head>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

These are used to generate the dynamic forms that implement non-remote links with :method.

You don't need to use these tags for regular forms as they generate their own hidden fields.

**For AJAX requests other than GETs, extract the “csrf-token” from the meta-tag and send as the “X-CSRF-Token” HTTP header. If you are using jQuery with jquery-rails this happens automatically.**

Comment: thanks for ur reply! I actually had read the Rails API but now I think I understand what the options is telling the protect_from_forgery do.
I am more concern on implementing the token to my c# application, would you kindly help provide some ref link? I am pretty on both ROR and webform in c#, my aplogize for so many questions :)

Comment: for the second part u mentioned, i have tried something like below in my c#:

        Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();

        postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postHeader.Add("X-CSRF-Token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        WWW www = new WWW(mainUrl + "login/", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), postHeader);

is this what you meant by adding the token as header?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but I think you've got the idea.

Comment: Its ok, may I just ask to confirm, the while line protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.include? 'application/json' }, does it mean, if the request is a json request, then it will verify it and if it does not pass, we return a null session?